# Check if OS is 32 bit or 64 bit before application install in C# windows application

Tags: c#, winforms, launch-condition

I want to validate a 32 bit application install on a 64 bit machine where I need to show some information to the user before installing the application. Is this possible?

I am using the launch condition (Not VersionNT64) for 32 bit and (VersionNT64) for 64 bit but that is not working properly!

Comment: Please post some code to help to find the error. Also check you have the lastest Msipackage installed.

Comment: What do you mean by before application install? Do you mean installer should check OS is 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: Or do you want to put a check in your application that if OS is 32bit do this else do that?,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand your issue, but if I assume that you have two different installers, one for 32bits and one for 64 bits, you would have to make a small executable that will wrap the two installers and select the correct MSI file.

```
Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem
```

will show you what kind of OS you are currently on.